# Compiling as3 project to swc file in flashbuilder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

i have a question and i'm hoping to find an answer here,

i created a flashbuilder project that contains some classes with functions that i use often, 
i have around 6 classes, would it be possible to compile these classes to a swc file so i just have to add the swc in a new project to access them?

Or isnt it possible to create swc's with flashbuilder? 
Maybe i could do it in flash but dont have any idea how to compile multiple classes into 1 swc. file.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but ive never used it before and couldnt find much about is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside FlashBuilder create a new "Flex Library Project".

It will take you through a new project wizard that is similar to an Actionscript Project. Once it is created, you can add your .AS classes to the source folder. As long as Project->Build Automatically is checked, it will automatically create (and update) a SWC file in your designated output folder, usually (/bin).

If you want to pick and choose particular classes or include external libraries, SWFs, or other SWCs, select Project->Properties->Flex Library Build Path there is a tab called "Classes" where you can select which classes you want exported into the SWC.

Answer (score 7):

You can just create a [library project](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_7.html) for this.

Move all of your code into this project and build the project.
The output will be a .swc file in the bin directory.

You can also do this from the command line using the [compc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_22.html) (short for component compiler) and incorporate it into an ANT task or a Maven build.

Cheers