# Is there an Actionscript to ABC Bytecode parser?

Tags: actionscript-3, parsing, bytecode

So, I have an app where users should define ActionScript functions.

What do I need to get the string whritten by the user and convert it to bytecode so that I can use it with as3-commons-bytecode?

**Edit**

I don't think I was clear enough. I need to turn: `if(!myValue) {...}`

Into this:

```
...
findpropstrict  private::myValue
getproperty     private::myValue
not             
iffalse         L1
...
```

Because with this ^^^^ code, I can use [as3-commons-bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html#asm) to do what I need.

I took a look at [this app's](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/#app=da4a&757d-selectedIndex=0) source code. It's very confusing, the project is old and the code is a mess, but it works. I need to find "where the magic happens". Can you show me the way?

Comment: Programs that inspect source code and emit something that is executable in some form are generally called *compilers*. "Parsing" is only a subset of compiling (generally what you do at the beginning, before generating code).

Comment: I thought of parsing because the as3-commons-bytecode library can receive a hole function as a bytecode string. So I only need to translate the ActionScript string to bytecode string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use part of this project :

[eval.hurlant.com/demo/#app=da4a&757d-selectedIndex=0](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/#app=da4a&757d-selectedIndex=0)

Check source , there is parser to ABC .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any libraries that do this for you, but to achieve this functionality you should parse user's input into function names.
For example, you can call a function just by having it's name as a `String` like so:

```
var functionName:String = "myMethod";
function myMethod():void
{
  trace("myMethod");
}
this[functionName](); //traces "myMethod"
```

Of course, if you wish to interpret advanced strings with getting/setting objects and their properties and any other user defined statements, that would require to write quite a sophisticated string-to-bytecode converter.

UPDATE:
There's also AS3Eval library that might do the job. Take a look at http://eval.hurlant.com/

Comment: That myMethod() function is not what I'm looking for. Maybe my question should be: Is there a "quite a sophisticated string-to-bytecode converter"?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly want to do? To compile "string" the string must be something meanfull for the compiler such as package not a simply string ( like 'asdas ' ). If you don't wont to use  flash/flex compiler you may compile AS to ABC with Ant or Haxe. But ther is a problem - how you will start this ABC?

Comment: It's not any string, I'm expecting the contents of a static function. The ActionScript syntax will be fallowed and only a defined set of variables will be available to use.

Comment: Maybe this will be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460027/compiling-as3-project-to-swc-file-in-flashbuilder

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for Haxe which makes it possible to compile Actionscript assembly language into ABC at runtime, but this is still lower-level than the Actionscript you normally write.

http://haxe.org/com/libs/format/abc

The most likely solution is a server or other process which can compile and return SWF content for you. Haxe has a very fast and straightforward compiler, but it may also be possible to use Tamarin or another solution for compiling AS3 on the server.

Actually, there is a runtime library for executing Haxe code, which again, is very similar to Actionscript. Might be worth looking into:

http://code.google.com/p/hscript/